# Como GRAVAR dados do android no MySQL usando webservices (AsyncTask)?

Tags: android, mysql, web-service, sql-insert, asynctask

tenho uma aplicação android que possui varios botoes em telas diferentes, devo juntar os botoes clicados e enviar pro MySQL. li sobre webservices (*http://www.androidpro.com.br/webservice/*) e precisa de uma AsyncTask pra fazer essa conexão.

`banco_mysql.java`

```js
package com.example.deadsec.gerflores_beta;



import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


/**
 * Created by DEDSEC on 24/04/2017.
 */

public class banco_mysql extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://IP:PORTA/BANCO/USUARIO/SENHA");
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String linha;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while((linha = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(linha);
                buffer.append("\n");
            }

            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String dados) {
        // Faça alguma coisa com os dados
    }
}
```

nao entendi muito bem como esta se conectando com o banco, como implementar isso na `Activity_final` pra reunir os dados (*botoes Clicados*) e como enviar pro banco.

me ajudem por favor.

Comment: Qual a dúvida em relação à conexão com o banco?
Veja que pela classe URL você passa como parâmetro o caminho, no caso, um banco de dados remoto.

Comment: @naydsonmariosa eu nao consegui fazer funcionar, nao sei se essa conexao esta certa mas não faço ideia de como reunir os dados e enviar pro webservice